# php captcha like go back to page

Tags: php

I have a website, I want to make a form type box, where the user has to enter a word (like "monkey") then click sign in.  If they enter it correctly, then they can see the log in page, if not, then they return to the page with the captcha.

I am not sure how to send them back to index.html using php if they are incorrect.

How do I do this?

Comment: I would integrate something like recaptcha into your side. Even the big players like twitter use it. Solid captcha with javascript so no redirecting from php-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will redirect user to "index.html". `Die();` is there to prevent script execution after redirection.

```
Header ( 'Location: index.html' );
Die ();
```

Comment: What I usually do is also set a session variable to indicate the user inserted the wrong word. I can then check for this variable in the page with the form and if is set output an error message.

Answer (score -1):

```
header("Location: http:foldername/index.php");
```